# Save XLSX file to a specified location using OpenPyXL

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, openpyxl

I'm having an issue saving my file to a certain location on my Raspberry PI (Raspbian) computer. I'm wanting the XLSX file to  be saved directly to my desktop rather than the folder holding the Python Script. When I do `wb.save("FileName.xlsx")`, It only saves it to the location where the Python Script is located.

Here's my code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws1 = wb.active
ws1.title = "1st Hour"
wb.save('FileName.xlsx')
```

Comment: `~yourname/Desktop` depends on your distribution.

Comment: You can use any string location for the `openpyxl.workbook.save` function

Comment: If the name of your user is p, you write `wb.save(' /home/pi/Desktop/Filename.xlsx')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay for any user, you can write

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import getpass
wb = Workbook()
ws1 = wb.active
ws1.title = "1st Hour"
wb.save('/home/'+getpass.getuser()+'/Desktop/FileName.xlsx')
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Always best to use `os.path` when constructing paths so that they are portable.

Comment: Yes, `os.path` is almost portable. An example of how `os.path` isn't fully portable. UNIX filenames can contain backslashes and e.g. `os.path.split` handles this wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

On windows systems: first you must copy the path, for example this path:
`C:\Users\obada yahya\Desktop\python`

Now you must add another `\` after each already existing `\` to the path:

```py
import openpyxl as xl
wb=xl.Workbook()
wb.save("C:\\Users\\obada yahya\\Desktop\\python\\obada12.xlsx")
```

Now it will work fine.